# How to use 2 separate databases, one for the write side and one for the read side. (two databases synchronized via eventbus)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, cqrs, nestjs

I'm using the `@nestjs/cqrs` module. How to use two separate databases, one for the write side and one for the read side. (two databases synchronized via eventbus)

Thanks

Comment: Hello, I'm trying to implement cqrs using nestjs, typeorm 
did you find any sample project that does the job ??? which i could refer ?

Answer (score 3):

With typeorm you can specify multiple databases by giving the connections names (if you don't specify a name the default connection will be used):

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      ...defaultOptions,
      name: 'writeConnection',
      host: 'write_db_host',
      entities: [WriteEntity],
    }),
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      ...defaultOptions,
      name: 'readConnection',
      host: 'read_db_host',
      entities: [ReadEntity],
    }),
  ],
})
export class ApplicationModule {}
```

Then in your feature modules, you import the entities by specifying the connection name:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([ReadEntity], 'readConnection'),
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([WriteEntity], 'writeConnection'),
  ],
})
export class FeatureModule {}
```

For more information, see the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#multiple-databases).